# EIA API : How to request data behind a proxy

Tags: python, api

I am securing some prices via EIA API, which works perfectly on my personal laptop but when I am at office I would need to use proxy and I am somehow not able to write a code to include proxy. The syntax doesn't recognize the word proxy.

I have tried calling proxies after API search name but it doesn't work.

```
   import eia
   import pandas as pd
   import os

   http_proxy  = "my proxy"

   proxyDict = {"http" : http_proxy, "https" : https_proxy}

   api_key = "mykey"
   api = eia.API(api_key)
   series_storage = 
   api.data_by_series(series='NG.NW2_EPG0_SWO_R48_BCF.W' , proxies=proxyDict)
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(series_storage)
   df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
   df1.columns = ['Date', 'Value']
   df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].str[:-3], format='%Y %m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked

```
import os
proxy = 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
```